# Why Segmentaion fault occur when calling member functons from thread functions?

Tags: c++, multithreading

i created a code in c++ to implement library management . 
i have a thread function which calling a functions . .

---another class have implementaions---

```
class employee
{ 

private:

----datas--

pthread_t my_thread;

public:

static void* worker_thread(void *);
char * getName();//function already written to return name
char * getTime();//function already written to return Time
pthread_t getthread();//function already written to return thread variable
}



 void* Employee :: worker_thread(void *arg)
 {
   pthread_detach(pthread_self());
   cout<<"Employee Time :"<<((Employee *)arg)->getTime()<<endl; //got error segmentaion fault
    cout<<"Employee Name :"<<((Employee *)arg)->getName()<<endl;
 }

int implementation:: Book()
{
 int ret = 0; 
 Employee *emp = new Employee;
 Employee *temp = NULL;
 temp = emp->gethead();

   th = emp->getthread(); 
   ret =  pthread_create(&th,NULL,&Employee::worker_thread,&temp);
   ....
   ...
}
```

When i print (or cout) the value using these getTime() and getName() method using these object i got segmentaion fault ..why ? i am using list of object as linked together .. Any problem on my code ?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Compare the type of `&temp` with the type you're casting `arg` to.

Answer (score 0):

I can see, that yours `void* Employee :: worker_thread(void *arg)` definition is missing a `return` statement.